# Node image instead of pointer icon in openlayers map

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know a way to change the pointer icons to node images?

Like the image below

[image]

I really like to have a little preview image from the node instead of hundreds of same looking pointers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

output the image's URL in your view which supplies data to your map.
create a new openlayer style, and for the marker graphic, give it your field name enclosed in ${}.

eg. add field_image to your view, set it to output 'url to file'
then add a new style and tell it the marker graphic url is ${field_image} and select an image style (eg. thumbnail)

use this new marker style on your overlay and you'll see the image show up as a marker icon.